# How to get UTF-8 speaker character to work in chrome

Tags: html, utf-8, icons, symbols, speaker

I am trying to get these 3 characters to work in chrome, they work in firefox

- https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f508/browsertest.htm
- https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f509/browsertest.htm
- https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f50a/browsertest.htm

In these pages it works and I can not figure out how, I even tried saving it to a complete page and it still did not work in the saved page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>UTF-8 Speaker Character Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        &#128264; | &#128265; | &#128266;
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Not a issue in Windows 10, issue is present in xubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7

Comment: What is happening instead?

Comment: empty square: http://i.imgur.com/g6Ke0jt.png